Material by emission (object from blender) doesn't display texture of material in Unity
i have made an old way to create a background with a sphere.
On blender 2.80 version, i create a sphere, put a material emission, add a texture, flip normals, activate backface culling.
I export it fbx format, activate modifiers, selected objets, mesh, i think configuration is good.
On unity, i try to extract material but it is a blank material. How to have the same object from Blender in Unity please?
Blender:
enter image description here
Unity:
enter image description here
Have a nice day!
Tried different configurations, other format (obj).

Just create a new material in Unity using an unlit shader? In general, materials from 3d software don't translate to game engines for lots of reasons and you shouldn't rely on it.

What is your primary file format option, because a lot of the times, material emission becomes incompatible. So as @MaxPlay said, you can create a new one in Unity or you could use the good old procedural way of doing things

Finally i used gltf format with a package and it worked well, thanks
